# javascript required input change input border

Tags: javascript, php, html, input, border

im trying to change the border if the user has leave the input empty after posting

well, i have tried:

```
<script>
   function required (id) {
       document.getElementById(id).style.border = "#FF0000 5px inset";
   }
</script>
<form method="post">
<input type='text' id='req' name='t'>
</form>
<?
if ($_POST)
   if (isset($_POST['t']))
        echo "u've done";
   else
        echo "<script>required('req');</script>";
?>
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to use [`required`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-required) attribute?

Comment: required isn't compatible with some browsers and i won't it effect i want a border

Comment: Apart from compatibility, you can style the effect as you wish with [`:required pseudo-class`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:required).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution with javascript :

HTML :

```
<form method="post" id="form1">
  <input type='text' id='req' name='t'>

</form>
<button type="submit" form="form1" value="Submit" onclick="myFunction()">Submit</button>
```

JAVASCRIPT :

```
function myFunction() {
  if (document.getElementById("req").value == '') {
    event.preventDefault();
    required("req");
  } else {
    alert("pas vide");
  }

}

function required(id) {
  document.getElementById(id).style.border = "#FF0000 5px inset";
}
```

## [CodePen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NNRqej)

Answer (score 1):

Change your PHP code to the following:

```
<?php // <- no short tag
if ($_POST) { // <-- add brackets
   if (isset($_POST['t']))
        echo "u've done";
   else
        echo "<script>required('req');</script>";
} // <-- add brackets
?>
```

Comment: nah, that make no sence

Comment: It makes clearly sense because without brackets, only the next line counts as statement.

Answer (score 0):

I think that i got a better approach:

```
<form method="post">
<input type='text' id='req' name='t' <?php if(!$_POST['t']): ?>class='required-input'<?php endif;?>>
</form>
```

Then in you put the "#FF0000 5px inset" in your css, creating the class "required-input" or whatever.

No intrusive scripts in your code!